# HTML Character Encoding tag do not work for me

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

Hello to everyone and sorry for my novice question.

I have an HTML document in which I would like to put some Greek Characters.

I have used the following:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

but the result is a sequence of such characters "Ξ Ξ±Ξ½Ξ±Ξ³ΞΉΟΟΞ·Ο ΞΞ­ΟΞ²Ξ±Ο"

Could you please advice a solution?

Thanks in advance and cheers to everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

Mybe your file encoding is ANSI, you can change your file encoding with notepad++ in encoding tab

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for responding. Unfortunatelly the file is already encoded in UTF-8 with Notedpad++.

Answer (score 1):

The cake is:

1. Make sure you are writing down your HTML code in UTF-8/UTF-16 character encoding, according to your configuration HTML editor, notepad, vim or whatever.
2. Set the value of the meta HTML tag exactly with the character encoding in which you have saved your HTML file.
3. This is optional, but is extremely recommendable to assure that the web server recognize your HTML encoding to avoid mistranslations.

**To sum up:** you have to be sure that your encoding file in which you leave your HTML code is the same character encoding you specify in the meta HTML tag, otherwise the client web browser will show the characters according to the meta info HTML tag and will probably make that unreadable.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond! Regarding the issue #3: How can I know which character encoding recognize my web server? If the UTF-8 is not recognized by my server, what are the alternatives in order to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: My problem solved - The encoding that was required was "Windows-1253" - Thanks everyone